# Como enviar dados de um Vetor para outra Activity?

Tags: java, android

Sou iniciante ainda, e estou com a seguinte dúvida:
Estou inserindo texto de um `EditText` em uma `array`, e quero recebe-la em outra. estou fazendo o seguinte:

```
String[] pedidos = new String[11];
```

E depois, ao clicar no botão "salvar", acontece isso:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnFinalizar){
        pedidos[0] = edtPedido.getText().toString(); //insiro dados do EditText em uma array.
        Intent intent = new Intent(mesa1.this, inicio.class);
        intent.putExtra("pedidos1", pedidos[0]);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

E na tela em que eu quero receber os dados, eu faço isso:

```
        String[] pedidosFeitos = new String[11];

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    pedidosFeitos[0] = String.valueOf(intent.getStringArrayExtra("pedidos1"));
```

Obs: Eu nao entendi o:  `String.valueOf(intent.getStringArrayExtra`

Pesquisei ao máximo, e acabei tentando o que o Android Studio sugeriu.

Comment: No caso de sua implementação você está passando item por item de um vetor. Enviando: `intent.putExtra("pedidos1", pedidos[0]);` e recebendo `pedidosFeitos[0] = String.valueOf(intent.getStringArrayExtra("pedidos1"));`. Nessa linha `String.valueOf(intent.getStringArrayExtra("pedidos1"));` estará convertendo um valor (que deveria ser um Array e não um item de um Vetor) para String.

Comment: **Uma pergunta**: Você quer enviar apenas um item de cada vez ou todos os itens de uma vez para outra Activity?

Comment: Cara, desculpa pelo erro, acabei confundindo array com vetor, obrigado pela correção. Com sua resposta, e com a do amigo em baixo, consegui resolver aqui, muito obrigado mesmo cara.

Answer (score 5):

Ao fazer isso `intent.putExtra("pedidos1", pedidos[0]);`, você não está passando um array(vetor no seu caso), e sim uma string, afinal, `pedidos` é um vetor de strings e `pedidos[0]` é a string que está na posição 0 do vetor.

Alem disso, ao declarar `intent.getStringArrayExtra("pedidos1")` você está tentando pegar uma string como se fosse um array, que não é o caso.

Altere seu código para:

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.btnFinalizar){
        pedidos[0] = edtPedido.getText().toString(); //insiro dados do EditText em uma array.
        Intent intent = new Intent(mesa1.this, inicio.class);
        intent.putExtra("pedidos1", pedidos);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Na outra `Activity`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
 String[] pedidosFeitos = intent.getStringArrayExtra("pedidos1"));
```

Agora, se seu objetivo é passar apenas um pedido(indice do array pedido), 
da forma que seu código já se encontra, basta alterar o `getStringArrayExtra` para apenas `getStringExtra`.

Mais informações podem ser encontradas na **[documentação do android](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/Intent.html)** e recomendo também que dê uma olhada no **[Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/index.html)** do android, está em inglês, mas ajuda bastante para quem está iniciando.

P.S.: [String.valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf) retorna uma representação em string do argumento passado, porém, neste seu código não seja muito necessário.

**Referência:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8892968/5524514

http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/index.html

Comment: Nossa cara, desculpa, eu escrevi errado, e acabei confundindo os entre vetor e array. Mas que bom que corrigiram meu erro, e me ajudaram. Muito obrigado mesmo cara.

Comment: @NilzonMartins deu certo a solução?

Comment: Não. não funcionou. O app da erro, assim que inicia, e fecha automaticamente.

Comment: @NilzonMartins então o problema provavelmente não é este da pergunta. Verifique no logcat os erros que são lançados quando o app fecha repentinamente.